# keras Installation with already installed Tensorflow GPU version in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda, keras, tensorflow

I have following environment in my windows 10 machine

Python : 3.6.0
Anaconda:4.3.1

**[image: Screen Shots]**

Tensorflow:1.1.0

**Screen Shots**
[image]

**OS:Windows 10-64bit**

Now when I am trying  to install keras into my system  I am getting a huge list of errros.

**[Detailed Error Log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24782582/)**

Now I have two questions here.

1. Can I install keras into my system when I already have tensorflow GPU version which was really hard to install?
2. If keras can be installed into my this system configuration then will my tensorflow GPU version work properly afterwards?

Comment: Conda has python version 3.6 but your python path points to python 3.5. Could this have anything to do with the errors? In addition, it should be possible to install both keras en tensorflow-gpu with pip. Keras can be installed afterwards. How did you install tensorflow-gpu? And what are the errors?

Comment: Please see "Detailed Error Log" hyperlink.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that. So basically the scipy install failed. Can you try to install it with conda. Afterwards you can try to install keras with pip again